# Cannot drag a window in Catalina Beta

Tags: parallels-desktop, beta, catalina

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta in a virtual machine on Parallels Desktop for Mac version 15.0.0.

I installed the Beta on top of Mojave what was working well within the VM. Unfortunately, after installing Catalina Beta, I cannot drag any windows.

When I click on the title bar of a window and drag, the window moves a few pixels and stops. If I repeat, I can barely make progress, progressively moving the window a few pixels at a time. Obviously inching along a few pixels at a time is unworkable and renders Catalina Beta useless.

This problem affects windows in all apps: the Finder, the "About this Mac" window, the Feedback Assistant window, and so on.

Any workarounds or fixes?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to go into the VM’s settings and on the Mouse & Keyboard pane change the mouse and keyboard to be “Optimize for games”.  The drawback to using that setting is that it automatically activates the “Mouse pointer sticks at window edges” function, with no way to disable it.

Comment: Interesting. I have always turned off that Optimize setting. Will give it a try.